# I wrote if condition block in DSL pipeline but condition matches also the stage is getting skipped

Tags: jenkins, tags

```
stages{
        stage('Update pipline'){
            when{
                 expression{  env.Update_Pipeline = true}
            }
            steps{
              script{
                  currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                  error("Updated pipeline & please re-run pipeline again")
              }
            }
        }
        stage('Checkout'){
            
            
            steps{
                script{
                  dir('app'){
                      checkout([$class:'GitSCM',branches:[[name:'*/master']],
                              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                              extensions: [],
                              submoduelCfg:[],
                              userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId:'Bitbucket-credentials',
                              url: 'git@bitbucket.org:exium-c2/exops-nodemon.git']]
                            ])
                            
                     //GIT_BRANCH= sh(returnStdout: true,script:"git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").trim()
                       current_tag=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git describe --tags --abbrev=0").trim()
                            
                      echo  "${current_tag}"
                      
                      
                       
                        }   
                    }
                    
                    
                }
       }
        stage('CD-Deploy'){
           steps{
               
               script{
                    if (( env.current_tag ='stg-v.2.0')){
                           
                            ssh -o    StrictHostKeyChecking=no                                     
 centos@65.0.194.82 "cd /etc/release/exops_nodemon  && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d "
                      }
                     
                }
               
           }
    
        
        }    
    }
  }
```

''
I have created a tag with stg-1.0,2.0..etc so once condition doesn't matches the stage[CD-Deploy]should skipped but my condition is matched still it is getting skipped. Please help to understand this issue. Thanks.
Note: My requirement I want to skip the stage based on tag if tag is not  starting with 'stg' need to skip the stage
output:

- git describe --tags --abbrev=0
  stg-v.2.0

''

Comment: change this  ````env.current_tag ='stg-v.2.0' ```` to this ````env.current_tag =='stg-v.2.0' ````